# Issue Trying to Load .xlsx from Shiny to Database

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny, rsqlite

I am having a hard time trying to code a Shiny app that lets the user upload a file and then with a Button it is supposed to create a new table on a Database that's connected through RSQLite, please see code below:

ui.R:

```
navbarPage(
"Ingreso de Data a Base de Datos",

fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
accept = c(".xlsx")
),

actionButton("Load_DB_Button",
"Load Data",
style = "bordered",
width = "100%"),

mainPanel(

tableOutput('contents'))
)
```

Server.R:

```
Load_Data <- source("Load_Data.R")

library(readxl)

function(input, output, session){

output$contents <- renderTable({

req(input$file1)

inFile <- input$file1

read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)

})

vals <- reactiveValues()

observeEvent(input$Load_DB_Button,{

vals$Load_Data_Out <- Load_Data()
showModal(modalDialog("Calculation Finished!"))

})

}
```

Load_Data.R:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)

function(){

BD_CA_IDAAN <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "C:/Users/CBarrios/Desktop/Ex_Files_Data_Apps_R_Shiny/Exercise Files/07_03/Database/DB_CA_IDAAN.db")

df1 <- data.frame(contents)

dbWriteTable(BD_CA_IDAAN, "Test Table", df1)

message("Running Code")
return("Some Output")
}
```

I just need it to create a Table on the Database with the data that was loaded through Excel. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Load_Data.R ? Is it a file ?

Comment: Is there an error message? You should probably name your function to call it in the server part, not just sourcing the Load_Data.R file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes I'm recommending:

- Your function is not named, so while it is defined, it is immediately discarded and not available. Store it with a name (I'll use `Load_Data_func` just to differentiate it from the `Load_Data.R` file and the function you thought you had, feel free to rename it) so that it can persist and be used.
- Your function is breaching scope by assuming that the data it needs is already created in a parent environment; it's typically much better (safer, recommended, etc) to pass its data to it explicitly. The function also returns something ... a static string, which you then store into a reactive-value, which seems unnecessary. I'd think this function should return either the data itself or something to indicate that it was correctly stored in the database.

  I'll go one (big) step forward here: the `dbWriteTable` thing seems a little fragile. As it is now, the default arguments are `append=FALSE, overwrite=FALSE`; if the table exists, then this will error. You have two options here, I'm going to implement #1:

  1. Add `append=TRUE`; you may choose `overwrite=TRUE` *instead* if you do not intend to persist data, purging the previous data each time.
  2. Create a randomized table name and return that table name from the function. If you go this route, then you will need to use a `reactiveVal` to store the table name separately from the data returned. (This option is not demonstrated here.)
- I'm generalizing the function a little so that *it* is responsible for using `readxl`. The assumed intent of the function is to do something with the data, i.e., store it in the database. Whether the data is passed explicitly (perhaps you would want sample data available, chosen elsewhere in the shiny interface) or passed as a file (which is the default), the function should do that part. My change here is to remove the file-reading from the main shiny file, instead just passing the path/filename. (Note that the function now really should be called with all arguments named, not just positional arguments. Not strictly required, but for clarity it makes sense.)
- Read in the data into its own reactive, and then use that reactive within the `output$contents` block (and optionally anywhere you want the raw data and do not intent to "query" using `DBI`).
- The `observeEvent` on the button press is out of place; I think the initial data read should be dependent on the button press, not on changing the filename, since it appears you *don't* want to read in the file until the button press. For this, I'm changing the reactive flow a bit.
- Under the assumption that in addition to a `Load_Data.R` file, you may have other files that do things with the data ... I've moved most library loading to the main file. (The exception being `readxl`, which is only needed by `Load_Data_func`, so it remains in `Load_Data.R`. It doesn't hurt to move it to `server.R` if you want.)
- I relocated the definition of the sqlite database file location to the top-level (within `server.R`), since in my eyes the function should not hard-code things like that.
- Again, assuming that you will be doing more things with the sqlite database than just dump data into it, you have two options:

  1. Store the database connection object (your name `BD_CA_IDAAN`) in the main `server.R` file so that all other functions/reactives (not included here) can have access to the already-opened database; or
  2. Open it, store the data, then close it immediately. My version of your function will support both: either pass the database connection object (and the data will be appended, database connection *not* closed), or pass the filename and the db will be opened, data appended, and db closed within the function.
- Optional: I don't know if the sqlite database is intended just for permanent storage of the data, or if you intend to run SQL queries against it. If the latter, than you might not need to use `mydata()`, though much of the shiny flow here should still remain. (If you intend to use all R functions for subsetting/reshaping/recalculating/... on `mydata()`, then keep `mydata()` as-is and work with it as a frame.)

```r
## ui.R
navbarPage(
  "Ingreso de Data a Base de Datos",
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
            accept = c(".xlsx")
            ),
  actionButton("Load_DB_Button",
               "Load Data",
               style = "bordered",
               width = "100%"),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput('contents')
  )
)
```

```r
## server.R
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)

Load_Data <- source("Load_Data.R")

BD_CA_IDAAN <- "C:/Users/CBarrios/Desktop/Ex_Files_Data_Apps_R_Shiny/Exercise Files/07_03/Database/DB_CA_IDAAN.db"
### Optional:
# BD_CA_IDAAN <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), BD_CA_IDAAN)

function(input, output, session) {

  mydata <- eventReactive(input$Load_DB_Button, {
    req(input$file1$datapath) # this is isolated
    dat <- Load_Data_func(path = input$file1$datapath, sheet = 1, db = BD_CA_IDAAN)
    showModal(modalDialog("Calculation Finished!"))
    dat
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(mydata())
  })

}
```

```r
## Load_Data.R
library(readxl)

Load_Data_func <- function(path, sheet = 1, db, data) {
  message("Running Code")
  if (missing(data)) {
    data <- readxl::read_excel(path, sheet = sheet)
  }
  if (is.character(db)) {
    # we were passed a file path
    db <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), db)
    on.exit({ DBI::dbDisconnect(db); }, add = TRUE)
  }
  # this either returns 'TRUE' or it fails with an error, nothing else
  dbWriteTable(db, "Test Table", data, append = TRUE)
}
```

<sup>*Caveat: I really haven't tested this extensively.*</sup>